# Salir de una función y retornar a main() en bash

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo un script escrito en bash en Linux. Tengo unas funciones, y lo que quiero es que el `main` por así decirlo se ejecute continuamente hasta introducir un valor específico por teclado. Quiero que cuando entre en alguna función, si se da algún caso en especial que me retorne a la función de menú para poder seguir operando.

El código parcial de lo que llevo es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

function function_A() {
    clear
    echo "Si quieres volver al menu escribe un 0"
    read -p "Valor: " VALOR_A
    if (( $VALOR_A == 0 ))
    then
        ## Aquí quiero que vuelva a pintar el menú. Pero se me sale del script
        return 0
    else
        echo "Seguimos dentro de A"
    fi
    echo "Esto no se debe ver si he puesto un 0"
}

function_B() {
    echo "Estamos en B"
}

while true
do
    echo "[1]: funcion A"
    echo "[0]: Salir"
    read -p "selecciona: " OPTION

    if (( $OPTION == 1 ))
    then
        function_A
        function_B
    elif (( $OPTION == 0 ))
    then
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Valor incorrecto"
    fi
done
```

Lo que quiero es que si por ejemplo entro en la función A, y luego pongo un `0` (Salir), quiero que me vuelva a pinta el menú y no se ejecute la función B, ya que es como un seguimiento de pasos, y si falla la función A no tiene sentido que en mi programa se ejecute la función B. Es como que me gustaría tener algún marcador del programa para poder dirigirlo a una etiqueta en particular en función de las opciones que elija.

Comment: En lugar del  `return 0` invoca de nuevo al mismo script. Si por ejemplo se llama `menu.sh` y tiene 755 de permisos, invócalo mediante `./menu.sh` y en la linea siguiente le pones un `exit 1` y ya está. Pruébalo y me cuentas. A mi me parece que me funciona bien aqui.

Comment: @masterguru Se oye bien, y funcionaría, pero de esa manera dejas abiertos más subprocesos y haces un uso cuestionable de la recursividad.

Comment: @Cuauhtli ya me lo imaginaba, pero en un script tipo menu que tengo lo hago asi para salir del paso... tampoco es que lo use demasiado, pero si se usa intensamente seguramente tienes razon.  De hecho cuando en un terminal lo estoy usando y en otro modifico el script para añadr más cosas, luego me peta al salir de el varias veces :-)  Era una sugerencia tan solo, si hubiera estado seguro lo hubiera posteado como respuesta, je

Comment: @masterguru Justo me imaginaba lo de preguntarte varias veces por la salida. No pasa nada. Igual sólo comentaba esto para quienes vean la conversación en un futuro, y vean lo que se pensó para abordar el asunto.

Answer (score 1):

Pongo una solución que se me ha ocurrido, aunque sea una chapuza, pero que al menos le pueda servir a alguien. La solución es manejar variables globales como `flags` para poder controlar el flujo del programa y poder entrar o no en ciertas regiones de código.

El código resultando es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

function function_A() {
    echo "Si quieres volver al menu escribe un 0"
    read -p "Valor: " VALOR_A
    if (( $VALOR_A == 0 ))
    then
        ## Aquí quiero que vuelva a pintar el menú. Pero se me sale del script
        VALIDAR='0' 
        return 0
    else
        VALIDAR='1'
        echo "Seguimos dentro de A"
    fi
    echo "Esto no se debe ver si he puesto un 0"
}

function_B() {
    echo "Estamos en B"
}

while true
do
    echo "[1]: funcion A"
    echo "[0]: Salir"
    read -p "selecciona: " OPTION
    if (( $OPTION == 1 ))
    then
        function_A
        if (( $VALIDAR == "1" ))
        then
            function_B
        fi  
    elif (( $OPTION == 0 ))
    then
        exit 1
    else
    echo "Valor incorrecto"
    fi
done
```

Mediante la variable `VALIDAR` permito/deniego el paso por la función B. Quería mirar las instrucciones `break-continue` ya que `goto` no lo permite `bash`, pero esta solución me ha parecido más sencilla y de andar por casa. Aunque carezca de toda elegancia.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que lo hagas todo por funciones. Explicándome mejor, que el menú también sea una función y se llame cuando sea necesitada.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function function_A() {
    clear
    echo "Si quieres volver al menu escribe un 0"
    read -p "Valor: " VALOR_A
    if (( $VALOR_A == 0 ))
    then
        ## Aquí quiero que vuelva a pintar el menú. Pero se me sale del script
        menu
    else
        echo "Seguimos dentro de A"
    fi
    echo "Esto no se debe ver si he puesto un 0"
}

function function_B() {
    echo "Estamos en B"
}

function menu(){
    while true
    do
        echo "[1]: funcion A"
        echo "[0]: Salir"
        read -p "selecciona: " OPTION

        if (( $OPTION == 1 ))
        then
        function_A
        function_B
        elif (( $OPTION == 0 ))
        then
        exit 1
        else
        echo "Valor incorrecto"
        fi
    done
}

menu # Aquí comienza realmente el script, ya que está fuera de todas las definiciones de funciones.
```

Espero que esta sea la respuesta que buscabas.

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado bien... Lo que quiero es que si selecciono que haga la función A, y luego, dentro de esta función, pongo un 0, quiero que directamente genere `menu` desde el principio, sin pasar por la función B. Es como una especie de implementar un `goto`, pero esa instrucción no está disponible en la nativa de `bash`

Comment: @Londo, con la respuesta que he dado, es como implementar ese `goto` porque haces que el menú sea una función, entonces cada vez que ejecutes `menu`, se ejecutará el menú sin pasar por nada

Comment: He probado tu idea y sigue sin funcionar como quiero. La secuencia que quiero conseguir es: 1) Introduzco un 1 (voy a la función A). 2) Introduzco un 0 (Le digo que salga de la función A). 3) Quiero que pinte de nuevo el menú, pero se me ejecuta la función B porque está incluida dentro de la opción A del menú principal. Si yo tuviera un `goto` donde introduzco un 0 dentro de la función A, podría ir directamente a pintar el menú de nuevo, sin necesidad de ejecutar la función B. No sé si me explico xD